# EXTRA_INITIAL_URI will not work no matter what I do

Tags: android, android-intent

Trying to point at a folder under my apps storage space and it will not work, what am I missing? Only opens the last place selected. Thanks!

```
DocumentFile f = DocumentFile.fromFile(getExternalFilesDir("/database"));
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/*");
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, f.getUri()); //file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.XXXXX.xxxxxx/files/database
startActivityForResult(intent, 7890);
```

Comment: You can only use an uri that you obtained before with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: I don't follow... So you can never start at an initial place? My users will not know where to go the first time.

Comment: That is the problem indeed. But on Android 11 you can start with primary or secondary partition.

Comment: So only real option is to create a custom file selector?

Comment: No, a custom file selector will not grant access permissions, like the original one does. BTW: startActivityForResult() is deprecated, but still widely used in the Android documentation.

Comment: Did you discover a solution to this? I am stuck with the same problem. Thank you!